# Creating random number within a URL with Applescript

Tags: parsing, url, random, numbers, applescript

This may be fairly easy to experienced applescript users, but I'm wondering how to randomise a number within a URL and get safari to then open that URL..

So for example.. http://example.com/something=(RANDOM NUMBER)&something=...

Would really appreciate some help on this..

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here's a example :

```
set randNum to random number from 1 to 20
tell application "Safari"
    open location "http://example.com/something=" & randNum & "something=..."
end tell
```